# hide products wihtout images from prestashop frontpage

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I tried to follow [this](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/623059-hide-product-without-images-from-frontpage/), but couldn't apply it to my shop. Besides that I need to hide the products with no image also from categories and featured products. 
The goal is to hide all products with no images only from the frontpage. 
Using prestashop 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Try this to hide the products in the frontend without disabling it:

```
UPDATE ps_product
SET visibility = 'none'
WHERE id_product NOT IN (
    SELECT id_product
    FROM ps_image
    GROUP BY id_product
)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I was thinking more of a template override.

Answer (score 0):

You can override assignProductList method in controllers/CategoryController.php

in this method first of all get the producut images with something like this:

```
$allImg = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT `id_image` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image` WHERE `id_product` = '.(int)($product['id_product']).' ORDER BY `position`');
```

then if count is 0

```
    foreach ($this->cat_products as $prodKey => &$product)
    {


        $allImg = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT `id_image` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image` WHERE `id_product` = '.(int)($product['id_product']).' ORDER BY `position`');


        if !(count($allImg)) {

            unset($this->cat_products[$prodKey]);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. It seems that it disables the product with no images from all the shop. As suggest https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/323340-hide-product-without-image-from-blocknewproducts/ it seems to disable the product only from the newproducts module.I tried the code with no success though. Ideally it should be applied to feaured also